# Near real-time data ingestion from SQL SERVER to HDFS in cloudera

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-kafka, real-time, cloudera

We have PLC data in SQL Server which gets updated every 5 min.
Have to push the data to HDFS in cloudera distribution in the same time interval.
Which are the tools available for this?

Comment: what is PLC and HDFS?

Comment: PLC stands for programmable logic controller. HDFS is hadoop distributed filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Confluent Kafka for this task (https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/).

The idea is as following:

SQLServer --> [JDBC-Connector] --> Kafka --> [HDFS-Connector] --> HDFS

All these connectors are already available via confluent web site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your data is being written in some directory in local FS. You may use some streaming engine for this task. Since you've tagged this with `apache-spark`, I'll give you the Spark Streaming solution.

Using structured streaming, your streaming consumer will watch your data directory. Spark streaming reads and processes data in configurable micro batches (stream wait time) which in your case will be of a 5 min duration. You may save data in each micro batch as text files which will use your cloudera hadoop cluster for storage.

Let me know if this helped. Cheers.

Comment: :Thanks for the suggestion. We got to read data from sql server. The data isnt pushed to FS. can spark streaming help in this case.?

Answer (score 0):

You can google the tool named sqoop. It is an open source software.

Comment: I have used Sqoop, its more like a batch processing. But I am need of a real time data ingestion from a SQL Server.